# Google maps and html geocenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use google maps api and the html geolocation to get my current location. Here is the codes. The console in browser does not throw any error or whatsoever. I want to fetch the location of me and set the center according to my location.There is also a bit of jquery in the beginning for some styling and plugins purposes.

```
function initMap(){

var usa = [[36.2116522, -113.7155883],[38.3679748,-105.2357827]];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.2116522,-113.7155883)
});

for(var i = 0; i < usa.length ; i++){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(usa[i][0],usa[i][1]),
        map: map
    });
    };
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
    map.setMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
    console.log('hi');
});
```

Comment: What is the question/problem with the posted code?

Comment: Your setting the marker incorrectly in the getCurrentPosition - you have already created the markers.  You need to update its position with the new google.maps.LatLng

Comment: @kalahari.ferrari well the first one is also not working where i added the map.setCenter. It's completely ignoring the navigation.geolocation.getCurrentLocation command even it's not showing anything when I put console.log(lat,lng)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation the `setCenter()` method accepts as a parameter an object of type `LatLng` or `LatLngLiteral`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral

That means you should slightly change the code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        map.seCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
    });
}

else{
    alert("Your Browser does not support geolocation or please allow your browser to get your current location.");
}
```

or

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        map.seCenter({lat: lat, lng: lng});
    });
}

else{
    alert("Your Browser does not support geolocation or please allow your browser to get your current location.");
}
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

You should also add an error handler function to figure out what exactly is happening in case of geolocation error. You can see the list of error codes in the following document:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionError

Please change your code to the following

```
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var lat = position.coords.latitude;
          var lng = position.coords.longitude;
          map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
          console.log('hi');
      }, function(err) {
        switch(err.code){
          case 1:
            alert("Error: PERMISSION_DENIED");
            break;
          case 2:
            alert("Error: POSITION_UNAVAILABLE");
            break;
          case 3:
            alert("Error: TIMEOUT");
            break;
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert("Your Browser does not support geolocation or please allow your browser to get your current location.");
    }  
  }
```

Can you see an error message now?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and I tried but still it's nothing. It seems like it's completely ignoring the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation method. I even tried to console.log it but the console is empty. I did some modifications to the code. and updated the new codes in the post.  Thank you so much for trying.

Comment: You should add an error handler as well. Please see my update. I also created a sample on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/qinabu/edit?html,output.